# RxJava: how to return the correct type of null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, kotlin, rx-java

I'm developing an app using Firebase, Kotlin and RxJava.

Basically, what I need to do is register an user using Auth from Firebase, if the user selected a photo, upload the photo and then save the user in the database from Firebase.

Until now I have this

```
RxFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .map { authResult ->
                user.uid = authResult.user.uid
                authResult.user.uid
            }
            .flatMap<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(
                    { uid ->
                        if (imageUri != null)
                            RxFirebaseStorage.putFile(mFirebaseStorage
                                    .getReference(STORAGE_IMAGE_REFERENCE)
                                    .child(uid), imageUri)
                        else
                            Maybe.empty<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                    }
            )
            .map { taskSnapshot -> user.photoUrl = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl!!.toString() }
            .map {
                RxFirebaseDatabase
                        .setValue(mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("user")
                                .child(user.uid), user).subscribe()
            }
            .doOnComplete { appLocalDataStore.saveUser(user) }
            .toObservable()
```

It's working correctly when the user selects a photo, but when it's not selected, the other maps are ignored, because I returned Maybe.empty().

How should I implement this to work with or without a user photo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at following construct:

```
        val temp = null
        Observable.just("some value")
                .flatMap {
                    // Throw exception if temp is null
                    if (temp != null) Observable.just(it) else Observable.error(Exception("")) 
                }
                .onErrorReturnItem("") // return blank string if exception is thrown
                .flatMap { v ->
                    Single.create<String>{
                        // do something
                        it.onSuccess("Yepeee $v");
                    }.toObservable()
                }
                .subscribe({
                    System.out.println("Yes it worked: $it");
                },{
                    System.out.println("Sorry: $it");
                })
```

You should throw an error if you encounter a null, and then use `onErrorReturn{}` or `onErrorReturnItem()` operator to return a default value that will be passed to next operator chain without jumping to `onError` in `Observer`.

So your code should look like this:

```
RxFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                .map { authResult ->
                    user.uid = authResult.user.uid
                    authResult.user.uid
                }
                .flatMap<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(
                        { uid ->
                            if (imageUri != null)
                                RxFirebaseStorage.putFile(mFirebaseStorage
                                        .getReference(STORAGE_IMAGE_REFERENCE)
                                        .child(uid), imageUri)
                            else
                                Observable.error<Exception>(Exception("null value")) // Throw exception if imageUri is null
                        }
                )
                .map { taskSnapshot -> user.photoUrl = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl!!.toString() }
                .onErrorReturn {
                    user.photoUrl = "" // assign blank url string if exception is thrown
                }
                .map {
                    RxFirebaseDatabase
                            .setValue(mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("user")
                                    .child(user.uid), user).subscribe()
                }
                .doOnComplete { appLocalDataStore.saveUser(user) }
                .toObservable()
```

But there is a problem with this code that any exception occurred before `onErrorReturn` would yield a blank uri and result in further chain execution that we do not want. If any other exception occurs onError should be invoked.

For that we need to create a custom Exception class and catch this thrown exception in `onErrorReturn`. Have a look at following snippet:

```
...
...

.flatMap<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(
                        { uid ->
                            if (imageUri != null)
                                RxFirebaseStorage.putFile(mFirebaseStorage
                                        .getReference(STORAGE_IMAGE_REFERENCE)
                                        .child(uid), imageUri)
                            else
                                Observable.error<MyCustomException>(MyCustomException("null value")) // Throw exception if imageUri is null
                        }
                )
                .map { taskSnapshot -> user.photoUrl = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl!!.toString() }
                .onErrorReturn {
                    if(it !is MyCustomException)
                        throw it
                    else
                        user.photoUrl = "" // assign blank url string if exception is thrown

                }
...
...
```

Hope it helps.